# Cut Cloud Run service from running - safety reasons

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Let's assume, I run a `Cloud Run` service of Google.
Let's also assume someone wants to really harm you and finds out all API routes or is able to send a lot of post-requests by spamming the site.

There is a Email notification, which will popup on certain limits you set up before.

Is there also a way to automatically cut the Cloud Run service, or set it temporarily offline? I couldn't find any good resource or solution to this.

Answer (score 12):

There are several solution to remove from traffic Cloud Run service, in addition of authentication solution proposed by Dondi

- [Delete the Cloud Run service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/services#delete). It might seem overkill, but, because the service is stateless, you will lost nothing (except the revision history)
- If you have your [Cloud Run service behind a Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

  - You can [remove the serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#delete-serverless-neg) that route the traffic to it
  - You can add a [Cloud Armor policy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#types_of_rules) that filter the originator IP to exclude it from the traffic
- You can set the [ingress to internal, or internal and cloud load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress).
- You can deploy a dummy revision (a hello world container for example), and [route 100% of the traffic to it](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration) (traffic splitting feature)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you provide some source to that?
Would be a top answer if included source!

Comment: Yes, of course, I added pointers to the documentation. Let me know if you need more helps

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you describe how I can automatically cut the service, like put something in my code which executes than, if I recognize that my limit is reached?

Comment: WHich limit are you talking about? Is it in number of call? Is it a budget limit? Can you share more context on your strategy?

Comment: Sure. It will be a budget limitation

Comment: For budget limitation you can use max instance on Cloud Run, like that you can know your worse budget. The other solution is to create a budget alert in the billing page and to use PubSub notification. On each pubsub message you check the project expense, and if it pass a threshold, you can perform actions programmatically.

Comment: The last point is actually super helpful and basically achieves what the question is asking for. Deploying a dummy version leaves the deployment history and settings (assuming you don't have it in an infrastructure as code way for example)

Answer (score 4):

You can't really "turn off" a Cloud Run service as it's fully managed by Google. A Cloud Run instance automatically scales down to zero if there are no requests, but it will continue on serving traffic.

To emulate what you want to do, make sure that your service requires authentication then revoke access on the offending user (or all users). As mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/services#disable):

> Cloud Run (fully managed) does not offer a direct way to make a service stop serving traffic, but you can achieve a similar result by revoking the permission to invoke the service to identities that are invoking the service. Notably, if your service is "public", remove `allUsers` from the **Cloud Run Invoker** role (`roles/run.invoker`).

*Update*: Access to a resource is managed through an IAM policy. In order to control access programmatically, you have to get the IAM policy first, then revoke the role to a user or a service account. Here's the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#programmatic) that gives an overview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helps me already.

Is there a way to integrate this into your code? I can't see an example there.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a Cloud Function (based on [this Google example](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#selectively_control_usage)) to act as a hard guardrail.

This receives billing quota messages on a pub / sub topic and, if over budget, removes the `roles/run.invoker` role from the Cloud Run service. This is finer grained than removing the billing account from the project and allows other resources in the project to continue to function.

The function and the Terraform / GitHub Actions to create the dependencies are in [this repo](https://github.com/iskarconsulting/google-cloud-run-template).

```js
'use strict';

const { ServicesClient } = require('@google-cloud/run').v2;

const GCP_REGION = process.env.GCP_REGION;
const GCP_PROJECT_ID = process.env.GCP_PROJECT_ID;
const GCP_CLOUDRUN_ID = process.env.GCP_CLOUDRUN_ID

exports.limitUse = async pubsubEvent => {

  const pubsubData = JSON.parse(
    Buffer.from(pubsubEvent.data, 'base64').toString()
  );

  console.log(`Current cost: ${pubsubData.costAmount}, budget: ${pubsubData.budgetAmount}.`);

  if (pubsubData.costAmount <= pubsubData.budgetAmount) {
    console.log(`No action necessary. Current cost less than budget.`);
    return;
  }

  console.log(`Current cost exceeds budget. Removing 'roles/run.invoker' from cloud run resource '${GCP_CLOUDRUN_ID}'.`);

  await _removeRunInvokerIamPolicyBinding(GCP_PROJECT_ID, GCP_REGION, GCP_CLOUDRUN_ID);

  console.log(`Role 'roles/run.invoker' removed from cloud run resource '${GCP_CLOUDRUN_ID}'.`);
};

const _removeRunInvokerIamPolicyBinding = async (projectId, region, cloudRunId) => {

  const runClient = new ServicesClient();

  const gcpResourceId = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${region}/services/${cloudRunId}`;

  const getIamPolicyRequest = {
    resource: gcpResourceId,
  };

  const policy = await runClient.getIamPolicy(getIamPolicyRequest);

  // Remove the 'roles/run.invoker' policy 
  policy[0].bindings = policy[0].bindings.filter(binding => binding.role !== 'roles/run.invoker');

  const setRequest = {
    resource: gcpResourceId,
    policy: policy,
    updateMask: {
      paths: [
        "bindings"
      ]
    }
  }

  await runClient.setIamPolicy(setRequest)
};
```